# Javascript - Creates new array instead of incrementing

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple twitter app to work on my javascript.
The code below is supposed to identify every tweets location and count the number of tweets per location.

However, it doesn't increment, it just creates a new array.
What is wrong with my code? How can I make it better?

Thank you

```
var Twitter = require('node-twitter'),
twit = {},
loc = [];

twit.count = 0;


var twitterStreamClient = new Twitter.StreamClient(
//credentials
);

twitterStreamClient.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Connection closed.');
});
twitterStreamClient.on('end', function () {
    console.log('End of Line.');
});
twitterStreamClient.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + (error.code ? error.code + ' ' + error.message : error.message));
});
twitterStreamClient.on('tweet', function (tweet) {


    if (loc.indexOf(tweet.user.location) === -1) {
        loc.push({"location": tweet.user.location, "locCount": 1});
    } else {
        loc.loation.locCount = loc.loation.locCount + 1;
    }


    console.log(loc);

});

var search = twitterStreamClient.start(['snow']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite `on tweet` callback:

```
var index = loc.reduce(function(acc, current, curIndex) {
   return current.location == tweet.user.location ? curIndex : acc;
}, -1);

if (index === -1) {
    loc.push({"location": tweet.user.location, "locCount": 1});
} else {
    loc[index].locCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works!
Could you tell me what is happening here? I'm guessing there's an index and that each tweet is going through it but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have an array of objects, but you acted as it was object of objects. And indexof could work only if you pass there the same object

Comment: `loc.loation.locCount` could work if you have `var loc = { loation: { locCount: 1 } }; ` , and it couldn't make a grouping by `tweet.user.location`.

Comment: You also could use `Array - find` if it supported in all browsers, but it not working in  IE : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find . That's why I used `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Array.indexOf is not matching as you think it is. You're creating a new object and pushing it into the array, and regardless of whether its properties match a different object perfectly, it will not be === equal. Instead, you have to find it manually:

```
var foundLoc;
for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
  if (loc[i].location.x === location.x) 
     foundLoc = loc[i];
     break;
  }
}
if (!foundLoc) { 
  loc.push({location: location, count: 0});
} else {
  foundLoc.count++
}
```